# how to make grided data and store z variable inside the grid

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have data:
X= array(30000) latitude (randomized) value in deg.
Y= array(30000) time in hour and Z= array(30000) data value of temperature.
I want to grid the data by 10 deg and 1hr and corresponding cells should be filled with the Z values.
I wrote the following code:

```
deg= np.arange(0,360,10)
hr= np.arange(0,24,1)

val2=[]                
for h in range(len(deg)):
    val1=[]
    for h1 in range(len(hr)):
        val=[]
        for h2 in range(len(x)):
            if ((deg[h] >= X[h2] >= deg[h+1]) and (hr[h1] >= Y[h2] >= hr[h1+1])):  
                val.append(h2)
        val1.append(val)        
    val2.append(val1)
```

when I run this code it's showing the following error;

```
IndexError: index 36 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 36
```

val2 is showing 35 empty list values. any suggestions for improvement will be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: What's not clear from the error? When you do `h+1` or `h1+1` you get to an index out of bounds (because you iterate `for h in range(len(deg))`). Change to `for h in range(len(deg)-1)`

Comment: Hi, I have implemented. now, I am not getting the error but the val2 showing empty list , but values are available in the variable in X,Y.

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Comment: Either [edit] the question or ask a new one

Comment: I am a beginner. I want to know is the right way of implementing/creating the data grids.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
deg= np.arange(0,360,10)
hr= np.arange(0,24,1)

val2=[]                
for h in range(len(deg)-1):
    val1=[]
    for h1 in range(len(hr)-1):
        val=[]
        for h2 in range(len(x)):
            if ((deg[h+1] >= X[h2] >= deg[h]) and (hr[h1+1] >= Y[h2] >= hr[h1])):  
                val.append(h2)
        val1.append(val)        
    val2.append(val1)
```

Val2 is list of 34X23